# Плавный скроллинг EditText

Tags: android

Есть EditText, когда в него вносишь текст по размеру больше чем он сам, то появляется скроллинг по тексту вверх-вниз, такой вопрос, как сделать чтобы при скроллинге прокрутка не сразу останавливалась, а плавно прокатывалась дальше ?

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте ваш `TextView` в `ScrollView`. Но только один дочерний элемент допустим для `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594713/3212712) надо обернуть `EditText` в `ScrollView`.